# Displaying multiple values in one Olingo property

Tags: java, odata, olingo

Sorry if this has been asked already. I haven't found the answer. I have an oData v4 API that builds an Olingo entity collection from a json string that it gets from an internal web service in my company. I can also get json for individual records so I can implement both `readEntityCollection` and also `readEntity`. Thus, I take the json string and build an entity that I send to Olingo for serialization in Java. So, I don't have access to the relational database in the back end. I can only work with the JSON string that this 3rd party system returns to me. The JSON string I get is something like this. Notice that the `order_items` are also in JSON.

```
{
    "id": 4703,
    "order_number": "123",
    "order_items": "[{"item_no":"1334","item_name":"Widget 1"},{"item_no":"1334","item_name":"Widget 2"}]"
}
```

It's simple enough to just display the `order_items` as-is as a `string` property, which is one big JSON string. But I was hoping that I could pass the `order_items` json array string to a pre-defined OData property. Because if I add the `$format=xml` option, it will still show a json string for `order_items` even if everything else is in XML. So my question is, can I convert a json array (from a string) and pass it to a pre-defined preoperty. (i.e. CsdlProperty) I hope I am making sense.

Thanks

Comment: In your example, order_items is not a "string" property, it's an array of objects.

Comment: Agreed. Is there a way to populate an Olingo property with an array? (i.e. the json array)

Comment: Based on  the json example  and the title, I don't know what you want to do. Do you want to covert the json to  POJO?

Comment: Hi, yes. Order items can have many items as there is a one-to-many relationship in the data. How can I populate an individual order_items property with an array of objects using Olingo oData for Java? Currently, the order_items property is a "string" and I am stuffing the json array in there as a string. Doesn't work out great because when I try $format=xml, my order_items are still in json. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I know I can create a complex type that holds "item_no" and "item_name'. But I would need a property that can hold multiple complex types, since I can have many. Not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found what I needed. What I really needed to do was to create a collection property for "order_items" that can hold multiple complex types. In other words, a collection of complex types, with each complex type having multiple complex values.

### 1. I created a new collection type, in `getEntityType()`, to hold my complex types:

```
final List<CsdlProperty> result = new ArrayList<CsdlProperty>();
CsdlProperty property = new CsdlProperty() // Complex types
.setName("order_items")
.setType(CT_ORDER_ITEMS.getFullQualifiedNameAsString())
.setNullable(true)
.setCollection(true);
result.add(property);
```

### 2. In my `readEntity()` implementation, I created a complex collection property and populated it with values:

```
List<ComplexValue> complexCollection = new ArrayList<ComplexValue>();
ComplexValue complexValue = new ComplexValue();
complexValue.getValue().add(new Property(null, "item_no", ValueType.PRIMITIVE, itemNo));
complexValue.getValue().add(new Property(null, "item_name", ValueType.PRIMITIVE, itemName));
...etc
complexCollection.add(complexValue);
Property orderItems = new Property();
orderItems = new Property(null, "order_items", ValueType.COLLECTION_COMPLEX, complexCollection);
...now serialize and send response
```

Olingo took care of the rest. Thanks to those who answered. If anyone needs further help with this, just send me a message.

Comment: I would need your help here.
1. How to were able to read the JSON file to olingo
2. How you were able to flow with object arrays in your data

Thanks

Comment: If you can also point me to any open repo of this, that would be much appriciated.